# How Can I get a range of values in a map for given lower bound and upper bound in an std::set?

Tags: c++, set, containers, std

Say I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main ()
{
  std::set<int> myset;
  int inf, sup;

  inf = 25; sup = 60;
  for (int i=1; i<10; i++) myset.insert(i*10); // 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90

  return 0;
}
```

I was trying to figure out if the standard library provides any methods, or combination of methods that would allow me to get two iterators `it_l, it_u` such that the range [inf,sup] is covered. I've tried to use lower_bound, upper_bound but I've misunderstood how they works. The idea would be avoiding to write loops (because I know I could write my own function for this task, but maybe there's some alternative I'm not aware of).

Update : Some examples of expected output would be (in my example)

`inf =25; sup = 60` I expect `{30,40,50,60}`

if instead

`inf=30; sup = 60` I expect `{30,40,50,60}`

if

`inf=25; sup = 65` I expect `{30,40,50,60}`

Apparently there's a misunderstanding, or maybe it's me I'm not correctly expressing what I want to do.

When I say inf and sup please intend them as extreme values of a real interval. Once you made such assumption what I want is to retrieve is the intersection between the interval [inf,sup] and the discrete set specified by an set objects. Is there some contradiction between what I just said and my examples?

Let `A={10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90}`,`B1=[25,60]`,`B2=[30,60]` and `B3=[25,65]`

For each `i=1,2,3` The intersection between `A` and `Bi` gives exactly what I've said in my examples.

Comment: I've corrected. My apologies.

Comment: Take a look at [`std::lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) and [`std::upper_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/)

Comment: As I said in my question, I've tried. But they don't do the task. I can use one of them to find the inf, and iterate until i find the sup. And as I also said if possible I would like to avoid to use loops. Unless there's a way of using them I'm not realizing now...

Comment: Could you clarify which elements you expect to be covered by the iterator pair in your example?

Comment: @mindriot done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

template <typename T>
std::pair<typename std::set<T>::const_iterator, typename std::set<T>::const_iterator>
infsup(const std::set<T>& set, const T& inf, const T& sup)
{
  return std::make_pair(set.lower_bound(inf), set.upper_bound(sup));
}

int main ()
{
  std::set<int> myset;
  int inf, sup;

  for (int i=1; i<10; i++) myset.insert(i*10); // 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90

  for (auto its = infsup(myset, 30, 60); its.first != its.second; ++its.first)
  {
    std::cout << " " << *its.first; // 30 40 50 60
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  for (auto its = infsup(myset, 25, 65); its.first != its.second; ++its.first)
  {
    std::cout << " " << *its.first; // 30 40 50 60
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Using [`lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound) for `inf` means that the start iterator will point to *the first element that is not less than `inf`*, and so fulfills the condition you want for the lower end of the range.

Using  [`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/upper_bound) for `sup` means that the end iterator will point to _ first element that is greater than `sup`_.  Note that the end iterator, in C++, always points *just past the end* of your range, so therefore `sup` will be included.

Edit to reflect the discussion in the comments (thanks to @Useless for pointing it out): Note that this works fine for empty result ranges, e.g.

- when both `inf` and `sup` are less than the smallest element in the set
- when both are greater than the greatest element
- when there are no elements within [inf, sup] (in your example, say `inf=25, sup=29`)

But if you pick `inf > sup` so that the returned iterators refer to different elements, then `its.first > its.second`, which would make the `for` loops (as I wrote them above) fail.  So it is up to you to ensure that `inf <= sup` (just like for any other `for` loop you might be writing).

Comment: Let me know if I misunderstood you…

Comment: It sounds what I want. I'm having a closer look. Basically I had a degenerate case that made me wonder if I had properly understood how lower_bound and upper_bound functions work. It is taken from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484285/stdset-how-do-lower-bound-and-upper-bound-work/40484406?noredirect=1#comment68213501_40484406 (the case is there).

Comment: But your other question had `inf > sup`, _and_ `inf` was greater than any element in your set. So, your lower iterator was `end`, and it's illegal to dereference that. This example has `inf < sup` and the results are all non-empty - you still need to handle these cases properly in general though.

Comment: @Useless That's a good point. If `inf > sup`, we would iterate out of bounds. The question is whether the `infsup` routine should actually be responsible for avoiding that; after all, if you try to iterate over an array using `for (int i=5; i<3; ++i) { }`, you're on your own as well…

Comment: The issue there I guess was that I interpreted for example myset.upperbound(x) like "find in myset the smallest element y such that x < y" and myset.lowerbound(x) like "find in myset the greatest value y such that y < x".

Comment: You know there's [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound) for all these methods, right? You don't need to just guess (although a book may be even better).

Comment: @user8469759 This understanding is correct for `upper_bound`, but `lower_bound` actually finds the smallest `y` such that `x <= y`.

Comment: @Useless empty results work fine (try `inf=sup=25`, or placing both `inf` and `sup` out of bounds at the same end); failure should only occur for `inf > sup` pointing to different iterators

Comment: @Angew Again... those names are misleading... (IMHO)

Comment: Examine the relationship between `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` and `equal_range`. Read the freely-available documentation explaining what they _actually_ do, rather than just assuming the authors were thinking of exactly your use case. The [SGI](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lower_bound.html) docs are probably better on motivation, although otherwise out-of-date.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just want this:

```
auto it_l = myset.lower_bound(inf);
auto it_u = myset.lower_bound(sup + 1);
```

This way, you'll get the half-open interval `[it_l, it_u)` such that all elements `i` in it come from `myset` and are `inf <= i <= sup` (i.e. precisely what you want). Half-open iterator intervals are what the entire standard library works with, so you should be fine.

Comment: So there's no chance, I have to iterate.

Comment: @user8469759 Define "iterate." My solution has at most one iterator decrement.

Comment: Sorry I thought I saw I while loop instead of an if.

Comment: Sorry but would lower_bound(sup) return an element >= then sup?

Comment: @user8469759 Yes, exactly. Technically, it returns an element `i` such that `!(i < sup)`.

Comment: @user8469759 I thought that was your point. You mentioned you wanted the interval `[inf, sup]` covered. I interpreted that you want the smallest interval `[l, u]` such that `l` and `u` are in the set, and `l <= inf <= sup <= u`. If these are not your requirements, can you edit your question to clarify them?

Comment: @user8469759 OK, I've looked at your last question edit, and updated the answer accordingly. Please try to re-word the question so that the textual description matches what you want. "Interval is covered" doesn't quite capture it. Clearly formulating your requirements might have even helped you to see the answer yourself.

Comment: @user8469759 Read your update again, and I do not understand why your desired interval ends at `60` when `sup == 65`. Please spell out the requirements in the question.

Comment: My apologies, the word "covered" is actually misleading.

Answer (score 0):

C++ works with *half-open ranges*.  That is, `[inf, sup)`, never `[inf, sup]`. The half-open-range idiom is well supported by the standard library: just use `std::set::lower_bound` and `std::set::upper_bound`. (Not `std::upper bound` etc). The closed-range one is not, you are on your own if you insist on using it. I would recommend adopting the standard ways and switching to half-open ranges everywhere.

Comment: What does the set_upper_bound does?

Comment: It's an autocorrect kicking in, or just a typo. should be just std::set::upper_bound. Fixing.

Comment: I don't understand what are trying to point out, thanks for the explanations anyway. How is your answer related to what I've asked? I'm just getting like "whatever you're doing, don't do it".

Comment: Do you understand it now? You've accepted an answer that does exactly the same thing. If not, google up *stl half-open range*.

Comment: I've accepted the most exhaustive/complete answer, that's it. Your one was more a suggestion than anything else.

Comment: I'm not after Internet points, I'm just worried that someone doesn't understand what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear why you say upper and lower bound don't do what you want.

lower_bound will return an iterator pointing to the first element you are trying to find (the first element that is not less than the argument)

upper_bound gives you the first element greater than the argument (so 70 in your example) but that's how stl iterators work, end points to one-beyond-the-last-element.

These 2 iterators can be used to make a copy of the elements if you really want a copy - but you can also just use them to access the elements of the original collection - and that range would include 60 but not 70 in your example.